# Is there a way to configure Currency or Accounting dropdown in Number Ribbon?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, ribbon

Is there any way to configure the list of currencies showed in the Ribbon (see screen shot)?

My most used currency, $, is not available in the default list and I can't found out how to modify this list (which includes some currencies I never used or selected).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the currency format on windows and that will push every application running on windows to use the currency symbol selected.

Step 1: Click start button and head to control panel.

Step 2: Click Clock Language and Region.

Step 3: Just under Region and Language click Change the date, time or number format.

Step 4: In the format tab from format drop down menu find and select the format you want to use. English US uses $ for example.

You can also:

Step 5: Click Additional settings.

Step 6: Select currency tab from the dialogue box.

Step 7: In the currency format field type whatever you desire.

Comment: Thanks, but not working for me. I want to keep my current regional settings, and only add the USD to the list of currencies in Excel. I added USD in  Additional settings but nothing changed in Excel.